# Union of Generic Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

In this program I made a generic linked list .Insert and Display functions are working fine but the union function is not working.I'm actually not sure that the function which i wrote is correct or not so,How do I perform union of the two given list.

```
import java.util.*;

class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;

    Node(T d) {
        data = d;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(data + " ");
    }
}

class List<T> {
    Node<T> first;

    List() {
        first = null;
    }

    void insert(T data) {
        Node<T> newnode = new Node<T>(data);
        if (first == null)
            first = newnode;
        else {
            Node<T> temp = first;
            while (temp.next != null)
                temp = temp.next;
            temp.next = newnode;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        if (first == null)
            System.out.println("EmpTY");
        else {
            Node<T> temp = first;
            while (temp != null) {
                temp.display();
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public void union(Node<Double> head1, Node<Double> head2) {
        Node<T> t = head1;
        Node<T> t1 = head2;
        while (t != null && t1 != null) {
            if (t.data > t1.data) {
                System.out.println(t.data + "\n");
                t = t.next;
            } else if (t.data < t1.data) {
                System.out.println(t1.data + "\n");
                t1 = t1.next;
            } else {
                System.out.println(t.data + "\n");
                System.out.println(t.data + "\n");
                t = t.next;
                t1 = t1.next;
            }
        }
    }
}

class DEMO {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Double> l1 = new List<Double>();
        for (double i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            l1.insert(i);
        }
        l1.display();
        List<Double> l2 = new List<Double>();
        List<Double> l3 = new List<Double>();
        for (double j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            l2.insert(j);
        }
        l3.union(l1, l2);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean appending a list at the end of the another? This is very simple, just make a link between the tail of first list to the head of the second list.

Comment: There are different uses of "union".... Do you want to "join" or "merge" the lists?

Comment: Why not just take the last node in the first list, and make its next node point to the root of the second list? If you want it in order, just do that then sort the entire thing?

Comment: @WasiAhmad Repetitions are not allowed if i append the two lists I'll be merging them

Comment: Repetitions are not allowed .

Comment: @SagarGoyal merge them first and then remove the duplicates!

Comment: @WasiAhmad how do I do that? And what changes can I make in my function?

Comment: If `union()` takes two lists as input, what should happen to elements already in target list (`l3`)? Anyway, your current `union()` logic doesn't create new `Node` objects, which is an absolute minimum, so you have work to do.

Comment: If you want to remove the duplicates, you can just do a `.contains()` to see if the object exists.

Comment: Why are `union()` arguments of type `Node<Double>`? Shouldn't they be `List<T>`?

Comment: If duplicate values are not allowed then you do not have a "List" data structure.  It is a "Set".  It is important to stick with standard names for data structures, and more importantly, to recognize the difference between externally visible behavior (duplicates not allowed) and _implementation_ (a list of linked nodes).  In your case you have a "Set" backed by a pessimal (maximally sub-optimal) implementation.  A linked list is an awful choice for the implementation of a "Set".

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
/* Function to get Union of 2 Linked Lists */
void doUnion(Node head1, Node head2) {
    Node t1 = head1, t2 = head2;
    //insert all elements of list1 in the result
    while (t1 != null) {
        push(t1.data);
        t1 = t1.next;
    }
    // insert those elements of list2 that are not present
    while (t2 != null) {
        if (!isPresent(head, t2.data)) {
            push(t2.data);
        }
        t2 = t2.next;
    }
}

/*  Inserts a node at start of linked list */
void push(int new_data) {
    /* 1. Allocate the Node & Put in the data*/
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
    /* 2. Make next of new Node as head */
    new_node.next = head;
    /* 3. Move the head to point to new Node */
    head = new_node;
}

/* A utilty function that returns true if data is present in linked list  else return false */
boolean isPresent(Node head, int data) {
    Node t = head;
    while (t != null) {
        if (t.data == data) {
            return true;
        }
        t = t.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```